# What is the simplist way to detect a mobile device in a Grails application?

Tags: grails, mobile

I have just started experimenting with Grails and would like to know the simplist method to detect a mobile browser.

I have noticed that when I deploy my application to tomcat and access it on a mobile device, the default Grails views are mobile views. It would be useful to be able to detect a mobile device in the controller and direct the user to a different view.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this plugin...

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-mobile

...and here's one of a few discussions at the Grails mail list...

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/iPhone-enabling-a-Grails-Web-app-td3206882.html

Answer (score 2):

I used this plugin to detect the browser. And it worked very well without cluttering my code.

https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/mathifonseca/browser-detection

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:browser-detection:3.3.0'
}
```

It also has the option to detect if it is a mobile platform on a gsp file.

```
<browser:isMobile> Mobile phones or Android, iPhone, iPad, iPod, Blackberry, etc. </browser:isMobile>
```

or in the controller

```
class TestController {

    def userAgentIdentService

    def index() {
        if (userAgentIdentService.isMobile()) {
            println 'Hello mobile device!'
            if (userAgentIdentService.isWindowsPhone()) {
                println 'Wow! Does this still exist?'
            }
        } else {
            println 'Hello desktop browser!'
            if (userAgentIdentService.isInternetExplorer()) {
                println 'Redirecting to Chrome download page...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PD: I know it's been a while since this question was posted but it may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [filters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) mechanism to detect if it's a mobile browser or not. you can see the list of [available variables in the filters scope](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filterVariablesAndScopes).

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getHeader('User-Agent')
```

...will give you things like "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1", from which you can guess both the browser being used and the system

Otherwise (I haven't tested this), there is a browser detection plugin here : http://www.grails.org/plugin/browser-detection

Answer (score 0):

Use grails spring mobile plugin. check this link http://jagadeeshmanne.blogspot.in/2014/02/grails-mobile-device-detection-using.html to find how to detect device and render device specific views using grails. use afterInterceptor and beforeInterceptor to change the views and device detection.